Issue with my ShoppingCart functionality inside my project
I'm currently learning C# ASP.NET Core, this is my project that i'm working on -> https://github.com/Slavilov/Bookshop-ASP.NET-Core-MVC-Application,
I have a problem with my ShoppingCartService.cs! When the programs goes to - the method public async Task AddToCart(int bookId) it successefully adds an item to the shopping cart, but when it goes to the last line -> SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart); i lose everything?? Why is that? Excuse my ignorance i would appreciate if anyone of you explain where my error is, thanks!
` public async Task AddToCart(int bookId)
 {
     var shoppingCart = GetShoppingCart();
     var book = await _bookService.GetBookByIdAsync(bookId);
     if (book == null) return;

     var cartItem = shoppingCart.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.BookId == bookId);
     if (cartItem == null)
     {
         shoppingCart.Items.Add(new CartItem { BookId = bookId, Book = book, Quantity = 1 });
     }
     else
     {
         cartItem.Quantity++;
     }

     SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
 }`

I've ensured Session is Registered in Program.cs:
I've added builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{ options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Adjust as needed options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; });
`app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthorization();
`

I've ensured that HttpContextAccessor is properly registered in my Program.cs ->
`builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

This is my whole code for ShoppiCartFunctionality ->
ShoppingCartController.cs ->
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{
    private readonly IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
 
    public ShoppingCartController(IShoppingCartService 
shoppingCartService)
    {
        _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
    }

    public IActionResult CheckSession()
    {
        var testValue = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue))
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "Session is 
working!");
        }
        return Content(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test"));
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _shoppingCartService.GetCartItems();
        var total = _shoppingCartService.GetCartTotal();

        ViewBag.Items = items;
        ViewBag.TotalPrice = total;

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult AddToCart(int bookId)
    {
        _shoppingCartService.AddToCart(bookId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult RemoveFromCart(int bookId)
    {
        _shoppingCartService.RemoveFromCart(bookId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult ClearCart()
    {
        _shoppingCartService.ClearCart();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

SessionExtensions.cs ->
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SessionExtensions.Helpers
{
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
}

ShoppingCart.cs ->
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public List<CartItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<CartItem>();

    public decimal GetTotalPrice()
    {
        return Items.Sum(item => item.Book.Price * item.Quantity);
    }
}

IShoppingCartService.cs ->
public interface IShoppingCartService
{
    Task AddToCart(int bookId);
    void RemoveFromCart(int bookId);
    void ClearCart();
    List<CartItem> GetCartItems();
    decimal GetCartTotal();
}

ShoppingCartService.cs ->
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SessionExtensions.Helpers;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ShoppingCartService : IShoppingCartService
{
    private readonly IBookService _bookService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private const string CartSessionKey = "ShoppingCart";

    public ShoppingCartService(IBookService bookService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _bookService = bookService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task AddToCart(int bookId)
    {
        var shoppingCart = GetShoppingCart();
        var book = await _bookService.GetBookByIdAsync(bookId);
        if (book == null) return;

        var cartItem = shoppingCart.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.BookId == bookId);
        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            shoppingCart.Items.Add(new CartItem { BookId = bookId, Book = book, Quantity = 1 });
        }
        else
        {
            cartItem.Quantity++;
        }

        SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    }

    public void RemoveFromCart(int bookId)
    {
        var shoppingCart = GetShoppingCart();
        var cartItem = shoppingCart.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.BookId == bookId);
        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            shoppingCart.Items.Remove(cartItem);
        }

        SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    }

    public void ClearCart()
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Session is not available.");
        }
        session.Remove(CartSessionKey);
    }

    public List<CartItem> GetCartItems()
    {
        return GetShoppingCart().Items;
    }

    public decimal GetCartTotal()
    {
        var shoppingCart = GetShoppingCart();
        return shoppingCart.Items.Sum(i => i.Book.Price * i.Quantity);
    }

    private ShoppingCart GetShoppingCart()
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Session is not available.");
        }
        var cart = session.GetObjectFromJson<ShoppingCart>(CartSessionKey) ?? new ShoppingCart();

        //Check if the session is retrieving the cart
        Console.WriteLine("Cart retrieved from session: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart));
        return cart;
    }

    private void SaveShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Session is not available.");
        }

        // Serialize and store the cart
        session.SetObjectAsJson(CartSessionKey, shoppingCart);

        // DEBUG: Retrieve the cart immediately after saving to confirm it was saved
        var sessionCart = session.GetObjectFromJson<ShoppingCart>(CartSessionKey);

        // Log the cart to the console
        Console.WriteLine("Cart in session after Save: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sessionCart));

        if (sessionCart == null || sessionCart.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Shopping cart was not saved properly.");
        }
    }
}

Views/ShoppingCart/Index.cshtml ->
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Shopping Cart";
}

<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Book.Title</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>@(item.Book.Price * item.Quantity)</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart", "ShoppingCart", new { bookId = item.BookId })" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<p><strong>Total: </strong>@ViewBag.TotalPrice</p>

<a href="@Url.Action("ClearCart", "ShoppingCart")" class="btn btn-warning">Clear Cart</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</a>

BookService.cs ->
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Data;
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Services
{
    public class BookService : IBookService
    {
        private readonly BookshopDbContext _context;

        public BookService(BookshopDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<Book>> GetAllBooksAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Books
                .Include(b => b.Author)
                .Include(b => b.BookGenres)
                    .ThenInclude(bg => bg.Genre)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Book> GetBookByIdAsync(int id)
        {

            try
            {
                var book = await _context.Books
                    .Include(b => b.Author)
                    .Include(b => b.BookGenres)
                        .ThenInclude(bg => bg.Genre)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);

                if (book == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"No book found with ID: {id}");
                }

                return book;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log or throw the error to see if anything goes wrong during the query
                Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching book: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task CreateBookAsync(Book book)
        {
            _context.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task UpdateBookAsync(Book book)
        {
            _context.Update(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task DeleteBookAsync(int id)
        {
            var book = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
            if (book != null)
            {
                _context.Books.Remove(book);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Author>> GetAuthorsAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Authors.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Genre>> GetGenresAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Genres.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

BooksController.cs ->
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Models;
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBookService _bookService;

        public BooksController(IBookService bookService)
        {
            _bookService = bookService;
        }

        // GET: BooksController
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var books = await _bookService.GetAllBooksAsync();
            return View(books);
        }

        // GET: BooksController/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
        {
            var book = await _bookService.GetBookByIdAsync(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(book);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Authors = await _bookService.GetAuthorsAsync();
            ViewBag.Genres = await _bookService.GetGenresAsync();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Book book, int[] GenreIds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AuthorId: " + book.AuthorId);
            Console.WriteLine("BookGenres: " + book.BookGenres);

            // Manually find the author based on AuthorId and assign it
            var author = (await _bookService.GetAuthorsAsync())
                                 .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == book.AuthorId);
            book.Author = author;

            // Map selected genres to BookGenres collection
            var selectedGenres = await _bookService.GetGenresAsync();
            foreach (var genreId in GenreIds)
            {
                var genre = selectedGenres.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == genreId);
                if (genre != null)
                {
                    book.BookGenres.Add(new BookGenre { Book = book, Genre = genre });
                }
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var error in ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (author != null)
                {
                    await _bookService.CreateBookAsync(book);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("AuthorId", "Invalid author selected.");
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Authors = await _bookService.GetAuthorsAsync();
            ViewBag.Genres = await _bookService.GetGenresAsync();
            return View(book);
        }




        // GET: BooksController/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var book = await _bookService.GetBookByIdAsync(id);
            if (book == null) return NotFound();

            ViewBag.Authors = await _bookService.GetAuthorsAsync();
            ViewBag.Genres = await _bookService.GetGenresAsync();
            return View(book);
        }

        // POST: BooksController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id, Title, Price, PublicationDate, Description, AuthorId, GenreId, ImageUrl")] Book book)
        {
            if (id != book.Id) return NotFound();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _bookService.UpdateBookAsync(book);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewBag.Authors = await _bookService.GetAuthorsAsync();
            ViewBag.Genres = await _bookService.GetGenresAsync();
            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: BooksController/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var book = await _bookService.GetBookByIdAsync(id.Value);

            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(book);
        }

        // POST: BooksController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            await _bookService.DeleteBookAsync(id);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}

This is my Program.cs ->
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Bookshop_ASP.NET_Core_MVC_Application.Services;
using Bookshop.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BookshopDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
           .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
           .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorService, AuthorService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBookService, BookService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IShoppingCartService, ShoppingCartService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Adjust this as necessary
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

BookshopDbContextSeeder.Seed(app);

app.Run();

When i say i lose everything i mean in the ShoppingCartService.cs method 'public async Task AddToCart(int bookId)' the program successfully populates var shoppingCart and var book and it executes successfully shoppingCart.Items.Add(new CartItem { BookId = bookId, Book = book, Quantity = 1 }); but once it gets into the method SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart); inside of it the first line of code is ->   var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session; the session is null.. and from there on i lose my populated shoppingCart with items etc. etc. and also sometimes altough not always i get error in the BookService.cs method -> public async Task GetBookByIdAsync(int id).
I know i have used ChatGPT to generate most of the code and i just assembled it! Don't crucify me!

your shoppingCart variable is only alive in the context of  the AddToCart function, With the 'lose everithing' I supoose that the changes didn't save properly, so the problem must be in the SaveShoppingCart() function, so we need that code

What exactly do you mean by "i lose everything"? What exactly do you see which makes you think this?

Also could you share code for GetShoppingCart and SaveShoppingCart ?

@J.salas ,@canton7 ,@Michał Turczyn i just updated my post, i don't know if you guys get notified thats why i'm answering here, excuse my ignorance it's my first post here, thanks!

Please answer my question

@canton7 When i say i lose everything i mean in the ShoppingCartService.cs method 'public async Task AddToCart(int bookId)' the program successfully populates var shoppingCart and var book and it executes successfully shoppingCart.Items.Add(new CartItem { BookId = bookId, Book = book, Quantity = 1 }); but once it gets into the method SaveShoppingCart(shoppingCart); inside of it the first line of code is -> var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session; the session is null.. and from there on i lose my populated shoppingCart with items etc.
i have updated my post and gave you my code

Right, so it throws the InvalidOperationException? So it's not that anything is "lost" - it's that your application crashes with an exception, because the session is null?

@canton7 yes you are on point, it does throw InvalidOperationException with the session being null.

@VelichkoSlavilov Have you solved this problem? I checked your sample (in the Github repo) and the cart feature works great.

When you say you are loosing all of your data, does that mean you are expecting saved data to be used somewhere else if yes then how you are trying to get the data?
So just to give you the context of this above repo which you are trying is the new functionality supported in the DotNet core, so basically HTTP is stateless protocol but if you want to store something in-memory or maintain in cache like redis or SQL you can do that as well.
If you are just trying out and don't have any requirement to implement redis or SQL as a persistent store then you can use in-memory cache, but to avail that you have to register it using below extension method.
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

This is nothing but the state management so you have to register the state management middleware as well, which you can avail using below middleware registration.
app.UseSession();

I hope this will help you to resolve the problem, as you haven't provide all the code and exact problem I have assumed few things so please feel free to comment on it with exact issue and I will be able to guide you.

Yes the data sh ould be passed to the public IActionResult Index() and from there to a view i updated my post and gave my whole code for that particular functionality, oh and also i have already added builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); and app.UseSession(); and that didn't work as well!
